# adding javascript to wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I got thrown at a project that is using Wordpress for generating websites. Once done, the team takes a copy of the generated static html code and puts it on some webhosting platform as a standalone website.

I am now asked to add some function adding dynamic behavior to a page by calling a webservice and add some of its data to that page.

I tried adding javascript using the custom html widget of the Gutenberg editor but it does not work well. I could make it work for simple things but firing a request did not work and it is hard to debug.

Wondering, is a plugin the right way to go for or are there better ideas?
I assume it needs to be some some php code adding javascript contained in html I guess?

Comment: you can user this WordPress reference link to enqueue JavaScript in WordPress page. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Maybe check out this article https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368, it seems clear

Comment: so looks to me like getting a plugin allowing me to insert js is the easiest way